# concatenate result from getRepository symfony

Tags: symfony

There is a way to concatenate two results from a findBy operation in symfony? I'm trying to concatenate an user object to a product array if the product was created by the user. My code:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $products = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')
        ->findById($this->getUser()->getId());

    if ($products[0]->getCreatedByUser() == 1){
         $userDetails = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
        ->findOneById($product->getUserId());

    //here somehow to concatenate the value from $user to the $products array
    }

    return $this->json($products, Response::HTTP_OK, [], [
        'groups' => ['products']
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Add sample input and output.

Comment: I don't think `->findOneById($id)` (which, unless you implemented it differently, is the same as `->find($id)`) does what you think it does.

Comment: No, it's not...

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object that holds pointers to the value from $user and the $products array. Alternatively you can create a array with (value,key) to map the dependency.

But why are you trying to do this on a controller level?

Wouldn't it be better to create a database (oneToOne)relationship? In this way you can query for products and it would load the userDetails as well. You could then access your userDetails in the twigview by using for example: `{{ products.product.userDetails.username }}` without needing any business logic in your controller.